# Should be simple, pass an object to a function (searched and couldn't find an answer)

Tags: c#, oop

I'm just being stupid here...thought this would be simple but got befuddled with my various attempts to make this work and all my online searches yielded nothing.

The first function (see below) is one of several that specifically serialize one type of object to an xml file and it works fine.  I'm trying to consolidate/refactor because I have 3 objects so I have  6 functions - 3 to read and 3 to write the objects.  I want to generalize and then move my functions into my business objects layer.  So when I try to generalize it, I need to pass in the object as an unknown type and then handle that.  In the first function, the type is known and like I said that works.  So the second function (below) shows my latest attempt to generalize but I'm not doing it right.  I want to pass in the object and the file path...

```
    private void ReadEmailConfigurationXML()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EmailConfiguration));
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(DataFilePath + "Data/EmailConfiguration.xml");
        EmailConfig = (EmailConfiguration)serializer.Deserialize(file);
        file.Close();
    }

    private void ReadXMLFile(ref Object obj, string fullPath)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(obj));
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(fullPath);
        obj = (typeof(obj))serializer.Deserialize(file);
        file.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Is the type of the object being passed in known at design time, or only at runtime?

Comment: What do you expect the cast to do?

Comment: You just need to use generics instead of keeping pair of methods for each type.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Not if the object type is only known at runtime, unless you want to do some nasty reflection

Comment: @BenAaronson, What you mean? typeof(T) already the reflection.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan The nasty reflection I was talking about was MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod()

Comment: @BenAaronson: If the type is only known at runtime, then the cast is pointless in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use generics to handle the different types:

```
private T ReadXMLFile<T>(string fullPath) {
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
  System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(fullPath);
  T obj = (T)serializer.Deserialize(file);
  file.Close();
  return obj;
}
```

Usage:

```
EmailConfiguration conf =
  ReadXMLFile<EmailConfiguration>(DataFilePath + "Data/EmailConfiguration.xml");
```

Comment: Hi folks thank you for the responses.  I will try what Guffa posted.  Not sure I completely understand it yet... but I haven't tried it yet.  The point is that at design time I have 3 different classes and I want to pass them in to one generalized read or write function.

Comment: Guffa, I have a global named EmailConfig to be the object that instantiates the class EmailConfiguration.  It made sense to me that I would substitute it for the variable (class) of type EmailConfiguration that you called "conf".  But when I changed the code you wrote (changed conf to EmailConfig global) it didn't work.  Still analyzing this...but any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: private T ReadXMLFile<T>(string fullPath)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(fullPath);
            T obj = (T)serializer.Deserialize(file);
            file.Close();
            return obj;
        }

Comment: called with:  EmailConfiguration EmailConfig = ReadXMLFile<EmailConfiguration>(DataFilePath + "Data/EmailConfiguration.xml");

Comment: @Sketch: If you already have a global varible named `EmailConfig`, then reading the data into a local variable with the same name won't change the global. Remove the declaration to use the global variable: `EmailConfig = ReadXMLFile<EmailConfiguration>(DataFilePath + "Data/EmailConfiguration.xml");`

Comment: global "EmailConfig" comes back null...I put in a break point to check it

Comment: ahhh...did not realize I was creating a local var.  I really am ignorant of how generics work...going to play with it I think I see what you're saying

Comment: actually it's not even about generics, I was just inserting code without thinking what it was doing  /-:  ok, going to start using my brain again.  WORKS!  Cool!

Comment: having trouble with getting the write function to work:

Comment: //private void WriteXMLFile(T obj, string fullPath)
        //{
        //    XmlSerializer writer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        //    StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(fullPath);
        //    writer.Serialize(file, obj);
        //    file.Close();
        //}

Comment: @Sketch: You need the generic type declaration also: `private void WriteXMLFile<T>(T obj, string fullPath)`

Comment: Got it working, I think I'm starting to understand reflection.  I still think it's an odd syntax, but thank you for showing the way!